# I am trying to connect to DB2 using python module ibm_db with SSL and I get the following error

Tags: ssl, web, db2, ibm-cloud, project

I am trying to connect to DB2 using python module ibm_db with SSL and I get the following error

```
import ibm_db
# import time,random
conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=bludb;HOSTNAME=21fecfd8-47b7-4937-840d-d791d0218660.bs2io90l08kqb1od8lcg.databases.appdomain.cloud;PORT=31864;SECURITY=SSL;SSLServerCertificate=DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt;UID=vpl67398;PWD=c8CTODyXcPc9RJTp",'','')
sql = "SELECT * FROM Users"
stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn,sql)
dic = ibm_db.fetch_both(stmt)
print(dic)
```

error showing

conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=bludb;HOSTNAME=21fecfd8-47b7-4937-840d-d791d0218660.bs2io90l08kqb1od8lcg.databases.appdomain.cloud;PORT=31864;SECURITY=SSL;SSLServerCertificate=DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt;UID=vpl67398;PWD=c8CTODyXcPc9RJTp",'','')
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0157E  Error opening a file. SQLSTATE=HY507 SQLCODE=-99999

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: The message tells you that the driver is unable to open a file, and in your connection string you have an unqualified filename (no directory path) for the certificate. Change the connection string to use an absolute path to the file, i.e. fully qualify the filename, and ensure that the account running python can read that file, then retry.

Answer (score 0):

SSLServerCertificate: A fully qualified path of the certificate file and the certificate file name. Only one fully qualified certificate name can be specified. The fully qualified certificate name must be unique and it cannot already exist in the keystore database.You cannot specify any wildcard characters or symbols that are specific to an operating system in the SSLServerCertificate property value.